# WiX installer registry keys get removed at shutdown/restart

Tags: wix, registry, regedit

Here is my xml file for WiX
https://github.com/Vaei/ue4cleaner/blob/master/UE4Cleaner/UE4CleanerInstaller.xml

The registry keys get installed and everything works beautifully until restarting the computer, then they get removed. If I do a bad shutdown (hold the power button or press reset on the case) it will remain.

Comment: Are you in a **corporate environment** with a **standard desktop environment**? If so, *are there any processes or services running that checks the integrity of the system? Could they be "cleaning" the keys on logout?* Can you verify that the package is listed as installed after the reboot? What about logout and login without reboot? Just in case some automatic process uninstalls it (doesn't explain why a bad shutdown works, but please just verify to be sure). Are you logged into multiple computers with a **roaming profile**? Could **group policy** be involved?

Comment: A `Procmon.exe` scan - which is quite involved - could reveal what processes remove or modify these keys on shutdown. I have mentioned this tool in several previous answers, but don't have the time to dig them up right now. [There are good videos on youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjKNx41Ubxw) showing its usage.

Comment: Not in any corporate environment, made this for regular people to use on their home computers. Three of us have the same issue (on completely different networks, even different countries).

Comment: On a clean virtual, install your application and reboot and verify that the problem really exists? First of all?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the MSI completely and try it again - deleting all temporary files and doing a properly clean build? Just to verify.

Comment: If you add these keys manually and then reboot, do you see the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The dirty shutdown scenario suggests to me that you have some running processes that are deleting the registry data when windows tells them to shutdown.  I don't think this is an installer problem at all.

Comment: Weird issue. No bitness issues in HKCR? Home system so no roaming profile or AD / Group Policy entanglements. Mystery.

Comment: I doubt it's all that mysterious.  I've had operations people claim similar things to me in the past.  There's always some simple explanation that isn't the installer.